# Image still persists in image holder of my app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

My image still persists in `image holder` container even after deleting the user's `pfp image` from firebase

here's few code lines from my proj:

**Deletion fuction:**

```
Future<void> _deleteProfilePicture() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    if (user != null) {
      try {
        setState(() {
          _isDeleting = true;
        });

        final currentUserDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('UserInfo')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('Username')
            .doc('info')
            .get();

        final previousPfpPath = currentUserDoc['pfpPath'];

        if (previousPfpPath != null && _image == null) {
          // Create a reference to the file to delete
          final storageRef =
              FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(previousPfpPath);

          // Delete the file
          await storageRef.delete();

          // Update the user's profile photoURL to null and reload the user
          await user.updateProfile(
            photoURL: null,
          );
          await user.reload();
        }

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('UserInfo')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('Username')
            .doc('info')
            .update({
          'pfp': null,
          'pfpPath': null,
        });

        // Introduce a delay before updating the state and showing the SnackBar
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

        // Ensure that the state is updated before showing the SnackBar
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            _image = null;
          });
        }

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: const Text('Profile photo removed.'),
          ),
        );
      } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
        // Handle Firebase storage exceptions
        print('Firebase Storage Error: ${e.message}');
        // You can show a specific error message to the user or log it for debugging
      } catch (error) {
        print('Error deleting profile picture: $error');
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _isDeleting = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Image holder:**

```
DecorationImage? _buildDecorationImage() {
    if (_image != null || widget.currentUser?.photoURL != null) {
      return DecorationImage(
        image: _image != null
            ? FileImage(_image!) as ImageProvider<Object>
            : NetworkImage(widget.currentUser!.photoURL!)
                as ImageProvider<Object>,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    } else {
      return _isDeleting
          ? DecorationImage(
              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                BlendMode.srcOver,
              ),
              image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/placeholder_image.png'), // Replace with your placeholder image
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
          : null;
    }
  }

                          GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      if (_image != null ||
                                          widget.currentUser?.photoURL !=
                                              null) {
                                        _showImageOptionsDialog();
                                      } else {
                                        _getImage();
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          width: 120,
                                          height: 120,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            image: _buildDecorationImage(),
                                          ),
                                          child: _image == null &&
                                                  widget.currentUser
                                                          ?.photoURL ==
                                                      null
                                              ? const Icon(
                                                  Icons.add_a_photo,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                )
                                              : const Icon(
                                                  Icons.edit,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                        if (_isDeleting)
                                          Positioned.fill(
                                            child: Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.black26,
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                              ),
                                              child: Center(
                                                child:
                                                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

> I am really unable to find any proper way to solve this issue. I want the image holder to be blank when pre-existing pfp img is deleted.
> does anyone know why this issue is happening?

Comment: Try clearing the stored image as well. And does it still persist when app is restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably because of that the `photoURL` of the `currentUser` object is not being updated in real time after you delete the profile picture and set the `photoURL` to null.

Like when you call `user.updateProfile(photoURL: null)`, it updates the `photoURL` in Firebase but it doesn't automatically update the `currentUser` object in your app.

**So you need to manually fetch the updated user data from Firebase**. You can do this by calling `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.reload()` and then reassigning `currentUser` to `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`
The code to that will be something like:

```dart
// Update the user's profile photoURL to null and reload the user
await user.updateProfile(
  photoURL: null,
);
await user.reload();

// Fetch the updated user data
user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

// And here goes the rest of your current code
```

And also then in your `_buildDecorationImage` function, you should check if `widget.currentUser?.photoURL` is not `null` and not `empty`. Like:

```dart
if (_image != null || (widget.currentUser?.photoURL != null && widget.currentUser!.photoURL!.isNotEmpty)) {
  // Your code
}
```

Try this and lemme know if it solves the issue or not!